# Axis to pixel conversion

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have developed a GUI in Qt4.x that shows the 2d map of environment which is being published by "gmapping" node. Now i want to add in that gui the position of robot which i think can be taken from /odom but when i try to draw it in my gui it shows very little change in pixels. My question is that how gmapping converts the axis coordinates to pixel information in /map.
i am using electric on ubuntu 10.04 with Qt4.x
Thanks in advance.
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38034/axis-to-pixel-conversion/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[MapMetaData](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/MapMetaData.html), published by gmapping (also included in the OccupancyGrid message), should have everything you need. Specifically, the map resolution in meters/cell, and the map origin.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1